# Swapping keys with xmodmap doesn't work in all applications

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, xmodmap

I would like to swap my control and command keys, and have done so using the following xmodmap config:

```
remove mod4 = Super_L
add control = Super_L
remove control = Control_L
add mod4 = Control_L
```

This works well in most cases, but some applications are not picking up on the changes.

For instance, Chrome still reports the control key as 'Control' and command key as 'Meta' when viewed on https://keycode.info/, and Firefox does the same except it reports the command key as 'OS'.

Similarly, Blender still has all shortcuts bound to Ctrl+Z etc.

Is there a way to force swap two keys for all applications? Did I configure xmodmap incorrectly?

I'm using ubuntu with the xmonad desktop, and gnome-tweaks doesn't seem to be working in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found keyd to be a great solution. It works at the kernel level, so will probably fix your issue.

1. Clone keyd from GitHub, build it and start the daemon.

```
git clone https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd
cd keyd
make && sudo make install
sudo systemctl enable keyd && sudo systemctl start keyd
```

2. Find the name of the keys you need to swap.
   Run `sudo keyd monitor` to get something like this when you press control and OS keys:

```
keyd virtual keyboard   0fac:0ade   leftcontrol down
keyd virtual keyboard   0fac:0ade   leftcontrol up
keyd virtual keyboard   0fac:0ade   leftmeta down
```

Make note of the key name

3. Edit the file `/etc/keyd/default.conf` to:

```
[ids]
*
[main]
leftcontrol=leftmeta
```

4. Finally, `sudo keyd reload`

Comment: Thank  you so much, that did the trick! This changes so much for me, I often use photopea.com for editing but I was never able to paste with the keyboard. Both ctrl+V and cmd+V didn't work.

Comment: For the record, I also had to add `leftmeta=leftcontrol` to make the swap complete.